# Extracting 'href' under 'a' tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

I'm trying to extract a link under "a href="link"..."

As there are multiple rows I iterate over every one of them. The first link per row is the one I need so I use find_all('tr') and find('a').
I know find('a') returns a Nonetype but do not know how to work around this

I had a piece of code that worked but is inefficient (in comments).

```
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://morocco.observation.org/soortenlijst_wg_v3.php')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

tabel = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})
for i in tabel.find_all('tr'):
#     if 'view' in i.get('href'):
#         link_list.append(i.get('href'))

    link = i.find('a')
#<a class="z1" href="/soort/view/164?from=1987-12-05&amp;to=2019-05-31">Common Reed Bunting - <em>Emberiza schoeniclus</em></a>
```

How do I retrieve the link under href and work around the Nonetype getting only /soort/view/164?from=1987-12-05&to=2019-05-31?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
link = i.find('a')
_href = link['href']
print(_href)
```

O/P:

```
"/soort/view/164?from=1987-12-05&to=2019-05-31?"
```

This is not proper url link, you should concate with domain name

```
new_url = "https://morocco.observation.org"+_href
print(new_url)
```

O/p:

https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/164?from=1987-12-05&to=2019-05-31?

**Update:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://morocco.observation.org/soortenlijst_wg_v3.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
tabel = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tablesorter'})
base_url = "https://morocco.observation.org"

for i in tabel.find_all('tr'):
    link = i.find('a',href=True)
    if link is None or not isinstance(link,Tag):
        continue

    url = base_url + link['href']
    print(url)
```

O/P:

```
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/248?from=1975-05-05&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/174?from=1989-12-15&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/57?from=1975-05-05&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/19278?from=1975-05-13&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/56?from=1993-03-25&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/1504?from=1979-05-25&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/78394?from=1975-05-09&to=2019-06-01
https://morocco.observation.org/soort/view/164?from=1987-12-05&to=2019-06-01
```

Comment: I tried this before but it returns an error message saying that a Nonetype object is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 0):

A logical way is to use nth-of-type to isolate the target column

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('https://morocco.observation.org/soortenlijst_wg_v3.php')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
base = 'https://morocco.observation.org'
urls = [base + item['href'] for item in soup.select('#mytable_S td:nth-of-type(3) a')]
```

You could also pass a list of classes

```
urls = [base + item['href'] for item in soup.select('.z1, .z2,.z3,.z4')]
```

Or even use starts with, ^, operator for `class`

```
urls = [base + item['href'] for item in soup.select('[class^=z]')]
```

Or contains, *, operator for `href`

```
urls = [base + item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href*=view]')]
```

Read about different css selector methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors